# subset the data and count the line in each file

Tags: python, function

I am trying to subset my data from a single file to two separate files and count the lines in each file separately.

```
   ID,MARK1,MARK2
sire1,AA,BB
dam2,AB,AA
sire3,AB,-
dam1,AA,BB
IND4,BB,AB
IND5,BB,AA
```

One file would be:

```
ID,MARK1,MARK2
sire1,AA,BB
dam2,AB,AA
sire3,AB,-
dam1,AA,BB
```

The other would be:

```
ID,MARK1,MARK2
IND4,BB,AB
IND5,BB,AA
```

Here is my code:

```
import re
def file_len(filename):
    with open(filename, mode = 'r', buffering = 1) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i

inputfile = open("test.txt", 'r')
outputfile_f1 = open("f1.txt", 'w')
outputfile_f2 = open("f2.txt", 'w')

matchlines = inputfile.readlines()
outputfile_f1.write(matchlines[0]) #add the header to the "f1.txt"
for line in matchlines:       
    if re.match("sire*", line):
        outputfile_f1.write(line)
    elif re.match("dam*", line):
        outputfile_f1.write(line)
    else:
        outputfile_f2.write(line) 
print 'the number of individuals in f1 is:', file_len(outputfile_f1)
print 'the number of individuals in f2 is:', file_len(outputfile_f2)
inputfile.close()
outputfile_f1.close()
outputfile_f2.close()
```

The code can separate subset the files just fine, but i am particularly not like the way I add the header to the new file, I am wondering if any better way to do it? Also, the function looks fine to count lines, but when I ran it, it gave me an error

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./subset_individuals_based_on_ID.py", line 28, in <module>
    print 'the number of individuals in f1 is:', file_len(outputfile_f1)
  File "./subset_individuals_based_on_ID.py", line 7, in file_len
    with open(filename, mode = 'r', buffering = 1) as f:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
 "
```

so i googled this site, added `buffering = 1` (it was not originally in the code), still not solve the problem.

Thank you very much for helping improve the code and cleaning the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `itertools.tee` to split the input into multiple streams and process them individually.

```
import itertools

def write_file(match, source, out_file):
    count = -1
    with open(out_file, 'w') as output:
        for line in source:
            if count < 0 or match(line):
                output.write(line)
                count += 1

    print('Wrote {0} lines to {1}'.format(count, out_file))


with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    first, second = itertools.tee(f.readlines())

    write_file(lambda x: not x.startswith('IND'), first, 'f1.txt')
    write_file(lambda x: x.startswith('IND'), second, 'f2.txt')
```

EDIT - removed redundant elif

Comment: Why do you have two different conditions that do the exact same thing? Just use `or`.

Comment: That's embarrassing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misreading you, but I believe you are just trying to do this:

```
>>> with open('test', 'r') as infile:
...   with open('test_out1', 'w') as out1, open('test_out2', 'w') as out2:
...     header, *lines = infile.readlines()
...     out1.write(header)
...     out2.write(header)
...     for line in lines:
...       if line.startswith('sir') or line.startswith('dam'):
...         out1.write(line)
...       else:
...         out2.write(line)
```

Contents of `test` before:

```
ID,MARK1,MARK2
sire1,AA,BB
dam2,AB,AA
sire3,AB,-
dam1,AA,BB
IND4,BB,AB
IND5,BB,AA
```

Contents of `test_out1` after:

```
ID,MARK1,MARK2
sire1,AA,BB
dam2,AB,AA
sire3,AB,-
dam1,AA,BB
```

Contents of `test_out2` after:

```
ID,MARK1,MARK2
IND4,BB,AB
IND5,BB,AA
```

Comment: could you explain a bit what does "header, *lines = infile.readlines()" this mean?

Comment: It's a useful way to unpack a list when you only care about the first few values. `a, b, c, *d = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` makes a 0, b 1, c 2, and d [3, 4, 5].